# Display a view with exposed form programmatically

Tags: 7, views

I show a view in my own module, like this: `$viewFromDrupal = views_embed_view('storage', 'block');`. The view is showing up, but the exposed filter is not working when I place the included view directly after an other view.

When the view `$viewFromDrupal` is showing at the top of the page the exposed filter works correctly.

Does someone have some experience with this?

*Should I include some extra files or something?*

Comment: Is the exposed form displayed inside the view or as a separate block ?

Comment: I tried both, but with no luck.

Comment: Is there any form alter maybe that prevents the display of that form, is there a specific template for the exposed form , or maybe a view template override  that is skipping the exposed form ? . Check in all custom modules + your theme

Answer (score 0):

So better to say in your question more details of how it doesn't work, but I'll take a guess...

Try

```
$view = views_get_view('storage');
  $view->set_display('block');
$view_markup = $view->preview('block');
```

I've done this before to render the View, that will give you some markup...

Then I've noticed that the "action" of the form could be incorrect, so you have to do a hook_form_alter implementation and set the #action to the current page path...I'm guessing what the value of $form['#id'] will be, you will need to verify that ...

```
    function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-storage-block') {
        $path = current_path();
        $form['#action'] = '/' . $path;
    }

  }
```